# Checking the elements in the array

Tags: c, arrays

The input is a mathematical expression (e.g. 1+2+3/4*5. or ((1+2)+3)/4)*5. ...) with dot '.' being the end of input.

I must write an algorithm which determines if the expression is written correctly following some arithmetical rules:

-all parenthesis must be closed

-two operators can't stand next to each other (e.g. 2++2)

-two numbers can't stand close to each other (e.g. 12+2)

-there is no '*' between a number and a parenthesis (e.g. 2(2+2)*3 )

-only numbers, operators and three types of parenthesis can be used

-there can't be nothing in between the parenthesis (e.g. () )

I pretty much got all of them covered but I just can't figure out how to make the algorithm recognize that this example is wrong:
9+6/5*(1+[2+3)]. - where the order of parenthesis are mixed up

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    char expression[MAX];
    int i, j, parenthesisNr = 0, mistake = 0, tmpOp;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){

        scanf("%c", &expression[i]);

        if (expression[i] < '(' || expression[i] > '9'){
            if (expression[i] != '[' && expression[i] != ']' && expression[i] != '{' && expression[i] != '}')
                mistake ++;
        }
        else if (expression[i] == '.'){
            break;
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){

        if (expression[i] == '(' || expression[i] == ')'){
            parenthesisNr ++;
        }

        if (expression[i] == '*' || expression[i] == '+' || expression[i] == '/' || expression[i] == '-'){
            tmpOp = expression[i];

            for (j = i + 1; j < i+2; j++){

                if (expression[j] == tmpOp){
                    mistake ++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (expression[i] >= '0' && expression[i] <= '9'){

            for (j = i + 1; j < i + 2; j++){

                if (expression[j] == '(' || expression[j] == '[' || expression[j] == '{' || (expression[j] >= '0' && expression[j] <= '9')){
                    mistake ++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (parenthesisNr % 2 == 1){
        printf ("WRONG");
    }

    else if (mistake > 0){
        printf ("WRONG");
    }

    else{
        printf ("CORRECT");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As answered in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40561977/4142924) by using a stack, to match the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle the parenthesis check is to use a stack.

To check different styles of "parentheses" or "brackets" push the opening parentheses onto the stack. When you encounter a closing parentheses pop the stack and check if the popped opening parentheses matches the closing parentheses.

Comment: We haven't learned about stacks quite yet, so I thought there was an alternative. Will look it up by myself though.

Only one more question, as I'm still new to programming, is the code I've written any good? :)